# How to create a group of Controls based on properties of a model class

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I'm writing a desktop application which contains some user permission management, and therefore I'm building a segment to manage all the user permissions.

Before I start hardcoding all the different types of permissions into the UI, I was wondering if it is possible, to let WPF do this dynamically for me.

To be more specific, I have a model with the user and his permissions (each User has a Role) which looks like this:

```
public class Role
{
    public enum Permission
    {
        None,
        Read,
        Write
    };

    public int id;
    public string name;
    public bool isAdmin;
    public Permission Usermanagement;
    public Permission Appointments;
    public Permission Events;
```

and for each Permission in this class I want WPF to create a Template with the name and a comboBox to select the kind of permission.
My first guess was to use a ListView/ListBox with a Template (that part is not the problem).

My question is how can I get the list of permissions as a source list for my Template, and afterwards how to bind the real object to it, so the right permission gets updated.

This is more a question about possibility, I could just hardcode my permissions and bind them one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a collection of name/permission pairs like this:

```
public class NamedPermission
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    ...

    public List<NamedPermission> Permissions { get; } = new List<NamedPermission>
    {
        new NamedPermission { Name = "Usermanagement" },
        new NamedPermission { Name = "Appointments" },
        new NamedPermission { Name = "Events" }
    };
}
```

and bind an ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Permissions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding Permission}">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="None"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Read"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Write"/>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```